# Konditionalis in indirekter Rede

Tags: subjunctive, subordinate-clause, indirect-speech

Wie kann man von dem deutschen Konditionalis indirekte Rede machen, wenn derselbe Konjunktiv sowohl im Konditional als auch in indirekter Rede stehen kann?

> Er sagt, "Er tut es." > Er sagt, er würde es tun.

> Er sagt, "Er würde es tun." > Er sagt, er [ ? ] es [ ? ]. (= He says that he would do it)

Comment: This seems similar to [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/61597/43989) question from a few days ago; though that was asked and answered in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Würde* wird korrekterweise nicht für die indirekte Rede verwendet. Das gilt besonders, wenn der Konjunktiv I zur Verfügung steht. Das ist hier der Fall.

> Er sagt: "Ich tue es." -> Er sagt, er tue es.

Daher zeigt die Verwendung von *würde* an, dass in der direkten Rede *würde* verwendet wurde:

> Er sagt: "Ich würde es tun." -> Er sagt, er würde es tun.

Anders liegt der Fall, wenn der Konjunktiv I mit dem Indikativ zusammenfällt, etwa wenn die Aussage lautet:

> Ich sage: "Ich tue es".

Da die Verwendung des Konjunktiv I für die indirekte Rede jedoch nicht (mehr) zwingend ist (andere hier mögen anderer Meinung sein) und außerdem der Konjunktiv II zur Verfügung steht, würde ich diesen Fall entweder mit Indikativ oder Konjunktiv II wiedergeben, den zweiten Fall jedoch mit *würde*.

> Ich sage: "Ich tue es". -> Ich sage, ich tue es *oder* Ich sage, ich täte es.

> Ich sage: "Ich würde es tun." -> Ich sage, ich würde es tun.

Eine gewisse Rest-Mehrdeutigkeit lässt sich dabei nicht ausschließen, besonders in der gesprochenen Sprache, in der *würde* verbreiteter ist als in der geschriebenen.

Comment: Das hat irgendwie einen Bezug zu [Modallogik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5_(modal_logic)): interpretieren wir "es ist möglich, dass es möglich ist, dass er es tut" gleich wie "es ist möglich, dass er es tut"?